# How can I access to ArrayProxy element in EmberJS ? objectAtContent is only solution?

Tags: ember.js

How can I access to ArrayProxy element in EmberJS ? objectAtContent is only solution ?

This is an example :

```
App = Ember.Application.create({});

App.my_list = Ember.ArrayProxy.create({
    content: ['dog', 'cat', 'fish']
});

console.log(App.my_list.length); // don't work
console.log(App.my_list.get('length')); // Work
console.log(App.my_list.objectAtContent(0)); // => Work
console.log(App.my_list[0]); // => not work !
console.log(App.my_list.get('0')); // => not work !
```

http://jsfiddle.net/stephane_klein/2ggrT/2/

Best regards,
Stephane

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to access to ArrayProxy elements :

Given `my_array` the ArrayProxy, and `i` the index of the object you want:

- `my_array.get('content.' + i)`
- `my_array.objectAt(i)`
- `my_array.objectAtContent(i)` (this is the method you should override to transform the content to something new)
- `my_array.get('firstObject')` if you want the first object
- `my_array.get('lastObject')` if you want the last object
- `my_array.get('content')[i]` works to, but you lose the benefits of the ArrayProxy.

Anyway, I suggest you to [read the ArrayProxy documentation](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ArrayProxy.html).

Answer (score 0):

App.my_list.get('content.0') also works.
So is: content = App.my_list.get('content'); content.get('0');